# Entity Framework ProxyCreation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have with my entity framework problem

I have function return my list :

```
    public IEnumerable<Entity1> GetmyEntity1ById(int Id1 , int Id2)
            {

        var myEntity1DbSet = Set<myEntity1>();
        var myEntity2DbSet = Set<myEntity2>();

        var query = myEntity1DbSet.Where(e => e.Id == Id1)
                        .Join(myEntity2DbSet.Where(e2 => e2.id== Id2),
                              e1=> e1.id,
                              e2=> e2.id,
                              (e1, e2) => e1

       );

return query.ToList()
```

When I Load first time date is fine

get list of System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1

```
List<object>  = 
{
  System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1,
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1,
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1
}
```

but when I add new entity in the database to my myEntity1
and load again data I get error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW4LH.png)

now my list is  System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1 +
                object myEntity1 : (new value stored in the database)

```
List<object>  = 
{
  System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1,
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1,
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1,
myEntity1
}
```

and it throw error

```
System.NullReferenceException
```

the problem if i restart my application after exception i will 
get my new entity

and will get

```
List<object>  = 
{
  System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1,
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1,
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1,
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity

}
```

what I saw is every time  when my list is mixed between System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1 and myEntity1  it throw error

I found Where is the error because my model myEntity1  contain myEntity2

```
    public class myEntity1  

        {
           public int id {get; set;}

           public myEntity2  entity2{get; set;}   

        }

public class myEntity2  
{
   public int {get; set;}
   public prop myProp {get; set;}
}
```

the exception is throw because when i m in the UI i try to get

```
myEntity1.entity2.myProp
```

My question how to force entity framework to return all time 
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1
 and not myEntity1 
because when it s return  myEntity1 all time myEntity2 is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find way to solve my issue 
at end of query I include my entity2 to be sure is attached

```
var query = myEntity1DbSet.Where(e => e.Id == Id1)
                        .Join(myEntity2DbSet.Where(e2 => e2.id== Id2),
                              e1=> e1.id,
                              e2=> e2.id,
                              (e1, e2) => e1
                            ). Include(e1=>e1.entity2)
```

it s true it solve my problem but until now I don't understand 
why entity-framework after i update entity in database 
it return  mixed between System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1 and object myEntity1  and not all System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.myEntity1??????